# Yosemite icon pack for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, icons

I have been searching for an OSX Yosemite icon pack but I was unable to find one. Some website was saying `file doesn't exist error 404`. So please help me find a good Yosemite icon pack for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the repository: `ppa:noobslab/themes` through Software Sources **or** through Terminal (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes`).

Add the repository: `ppa:tualatrix/ppa` through Software Sources **or** through Terminal (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`).

Run `sudo apt-get update`.

Then install the `macbuntu-icons-v6` and `ubuntu-tweak` packages through Software Center **or** Terminal (`sudo apt-get install macbuntu-icons-v6 ubuntu-tweak`).

Open Ubuntu Tweak. Click on "Themes", then "Icons". Select "Macbuntu-os".

You should now have OS X Yosemite-like icons.

Comment: sorry it didn't worked for me it is saying  E: Unable to locate package macbuntu-icons-v6

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you have to run `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install macbuntu-icons-v6 ubuntu-tweak`.

Comment: I did this also but nothing changed

Comment: After `sudo apt-get update` run `sudo apt-get install macbuntu-icons-v6 ubuntu-tweak` again. Did you do the `sudo add-apt-repository ...`

Comment: Yes I did this too

Comment: I think I have a problem in locating e and w . I have posted another question for that

Comment: What do you mean by "e and w"?

Comment: In sudo apt-get update at last of this command it says                   W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: "W:" = "Warning:" and "E:" = "Error:"

Comment: Can you find Ubuntu Tweak in the Software Center?

Comment: yes i am having ubuntu tweak

Comment: Did you do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`? If so, you should be able to find something named like "Macbuntu" in the Software Center.